# sqlite query - add key to records between null records?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working on querying some system logs that are stored in a database, and unfortunately the vendor did a very poor job of creating the database structure in terms of table relationships.  The reporting tool I typically use for this sort of thing relies on standards SQLite queries(no scripting/coding) and I would prefer to kick this report on user actions in the system out using that standard reporting tool so it can be scheduled and monitored to ensure it runs.

These logs list actions users perform in the system and I need to tie 2 tables together to get the full report of what they have been up to.

**Table 1:**  The vendor was kind enough to include a key in this one.

```
Key                     Other_Columns
-------------------------------------
jdoe|20140122|093537    stuff
jdoe3|20140122|093657   stuff
jdoe2|20140122|151644   stuff
```

**Table 2:** No key in this one, yet it ties back to the other table.

```
UID     Date        Time       Server    Action
------------------------------------------------
jdoe    1/22/2014   9:35:37
jdoe    1/22/2014   9:35:37    server1   action1
jdoe    1/22/2014   9:35:41    server1   action2
jdoe3   1/22/2014   9:36:57
jdoe3   1/22/2014   9:36:58    server3   action1
jdoe3   1/22/2014   9:37:01    server4   action2
jdoe2   1/22/2014   15:16:44
jdoe2   1/22/2014   15:16:44   server2   action1
jdoe2   1/22/2014   15:16:46   server2   action2
jdoe2   1/22/2014   15:16:49   server2   action3
```

Now to make this more interesting, you will notice the Key in table 1 uses the timestamp as part of it.  The timestamp matches the first timestamp in table 2 for a user where Server & Action are blank.  If you query table 2 and sort by date, then time, every log section for what the user does begins with a timestamp and a blank server & action entry.  The only way I can think of to join these is by somehow creating a key for table 2 using the UID, Date, Time columns, but I need to apply the same key to every row between the null action/server rows.  This has me stumped.

I am thinking I need to query table 2 by itself that creates the below temp table, and then join that back to table 1, but I have no idea how I could write a query that would generate the output below from table 2:

```
UID      Date         Time       Server     Action     Key
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
jdoe     1/22/2014    9:35:37                          jdoe|20140122|093537
jdoe     1/22/2014    9:35:37    server1    action1    jdoe|20140122|093537
jdoe     1/22/2014    9:35:41    server1    action2    jdoe|20140122|093537
jdoe3    1/22/2014    9:36:57                          jdoe3|20140122|093657
jdoe3    1/22/2014    9:36:58    server3    action1    jdoe3|20140122|093657
jdoe3    1/22/2014    9:37:01    server4    action2    jdoe3|20140122|093657
jdoe2    1/22/2014    15:16:44                         jdoe2|20140122|151644
jdoe2    1/22/2014    15:16:44   server2    action1    jdoe2|20140122|151644
jdoe2    1/22/2014    15:16:46   server2    action2    jdoe2|20140122|151644
jdoe2    1/22/2014    15:16:49   server2    action3    jdoe2|20140122|151644
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if it is, I am hoping someone would know.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
select t2.*,
       (select "key"
        from table1 t1
        where t1."key" >= t2.uid || '|' || strftime(date, '%Y%m%d')
        order by t1."key"
        limit 1
       ) as "Key"
from table2 t2;
```

It finds the first key larger than the `uid` concatenated to the date.  That should be the one you want.

Comment: That almost worked!  I actually just realized that table 1 doesn't always have a matching record in table 2.  Table 1 contains additional info about actions taken by the user, but not everything they do generates logs at this detail(think I figured out why they split this across tables now), and that's resulting in the generated "Key" being inaccurate in t2 if there isn't a match in t1.

Comment: @user3246693 . . . You can add a `where` condition, something like `t1."key" like t2.uid || '|' || strftime(date, '%Y%m%d') || '%'`.

Answer (score 0):

That date format is not supported by SQLite.
You have to use string operations to extract the date fields:

```
SELECT *,
       Table2.UID || '|' ||
       CASE
       WHEN Table2.Date LIKE '__/__/____' THEN substr(Table2.Date, 7, 4) ||        substr(Table2.Date, 4, 2) ||        substr(Table2.Date, 1, 2)
       WHEN Table2.Date LIKE '_/__/____'  THEN substr(Table2.Date, 6, 4) ||        substr(Table2.Date, 3, 2) || '0' || substr(Table2.Date, 1, 1)
       WHEN Table2.Date LIKE '__/_/____'  THEN substr(Table2.Date, 6, 4) || '0' || substr(Table2.Date, 4, 1) ||        substr(Table2.Date, 1, 2)
       WHEN Table2.Date LIKE '_/_/____'   THEN substr(Table2.Date, 5, 4) || '0' || substr(Table2.Date, 3, 1) || '0' || substr(Table2.Date, 1, 1)
       END || '|' ||
       CASE
       WHEN Table2.Time LIKE '__:__:__' THEN        substr(Table2.time, 1, 2) || substr(Table2.time, 4, 2) || substr(Table2.time, 7, 2)
       WHEN Table2.Time LIKE '_:__:__'  THEN '0' || substr(Table2.time, 1, 1) || substr(Table2.time, 3, 2) || substr(Table2.time, 6, 2)
       END AS T2Key
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Key = T2Key
ORDER BY Date,
         Time
```

Comment: Thank you for the catch, the date format actually got screwed up by Excel.  I copied some data out of the table and into MS Excel so I could scrub out the actual user data before posting here.  I just now realized that Excel reformatted my dates.